# How do you hide overflow on the left with an image floated to the right when you have a span with contents wider than the parent?

Tags: html, css

My headerDiv has two objects, a title and an image.  I want the title to display on the left and the image to display on the right. The title will be dynamically changed to varying lengths.  The width of the headerDiv should stay constant.  How do I hide the overflow in the h1 tag and display the img tag floated on the right of the header div?   The span tag is pushing the image to the next line when it is populated.

```
.headerDiv{
  width: 120px
}

h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100px;
}

img{
  width: 20px;
  float: right;
}


<div class="headerDiv>
  <h1>
    <span title="text">
      <spring:message code="${title}" text="${title}" />
      <span style="font-weight: normal;">Text</span>
    </span>
  </h1>
  <img src="image.gif"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out different values for the "display" style (inline-block, block).

Comment: Hopes that helps... I did not entire understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move the img tag into the `h1` tag and adjust width of `h1` to accommodate?

Comment: if I put the img tag in to the h1 it will be hidden with the overflow.  That's why they're separate.

Comment: In the CSS portion, you put just "headerDiv", did you forget to put in the period so it's ".headerDiv" or is that a typo in your post? If you did forget, try putting in the period as headerDiv is currently not being restricted to 120px and may look incorrect.

Comment: It seems to be displaying properly in jsfiddle with the code you provided or is this incorrect? http://jsfiddle.net/WY6uY/1/

Comment: Thanks waynebo.  I was missing the float:left in my code, but added it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the gif as background image and define a margin-right for your h1 to keep it from moving over the image.

Comment: I will need the image to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

i create code pen for you, i guess this is what you're looking for [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/bhimbim/pen/NXVEVd). Please ask if you need further explanation.

HTML

```
<button type="button">
  <span class="Name">Ibrahim Aziz asd asd asd asd asd asd</span>
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/user-group-512.png"/>
</button>
```

CSS

```
button
{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

button img
{
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  align-self: center;
}

button span.Name
{
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Thank you !.